# SUM(SALARY) when ID is distinct

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, decode, sqlplus

I am having trouble trying to solve this problem, I would like to only add a salary up if the 
employee's id is distinct. I thought I could do this using the decode() function but I am having trouble defining an expression suitable. I was aiming for something like

```
SUM(DECODE(S.ID,IS DISTINCT,S.SALARY))
```

But this isn't going to work!

So the full query looks like

```
SELECT B.ID, SUM(S.SALARY), COUNT(DISTINCT S.ID), COUNT(DISTINCT RM.MEMBER_ID)
FROM BRANCH B 
INNER JOIN STAFF S ON S.BRANCH_ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN RECRUIT_MEMBER RM ON RM.BRANCH_ID = B.ID
GROUP BY B.ID;
```

But the problem is with `SUM(S.SALARY)` it's adding up salaries from duplicate ID's

Comment: Ok managed to solve it! If anyone's interested.. I solved this by creating new views to contain the data, then instead of inner joins I just selected what I wanted from those views..! Thanks to anyone who gave advice!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `DECODE`, but this should work:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(S.SALARY)
FROM <table> S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT ID FROM <table> WHERE ID=S.ID GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)
```

Comment: Cheers for the help but it unfortunately doesn't work my problem is i have multiple inner joins currently in the query ill add the full query up!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this...

```
SELECT E.ID, SUM(E.Salary)
FROM Employers E
WHERE E.ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT E2.ID FROM Employers E2)
GROUP BY E.ID
```

If not, perhaps you could post some sample data so that I can understand better

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY` in outer query.

Comment: Cheers for the help but it unfortunately doesn't work my problem is i have multiple inner joins currently in the query ill add the full query up!

Answer (score 0):

The joins are introducing duplicate rows.  One way to fix this is by adding a row number to sequentially identify different ids.  The real way would be to fix the joins so this doesn't happen, but here is the first way:

```
SELECT B.ID, SUM(CASE WHEN SEQNUM = 1 THEN S.SALARY END),
       COUNT(DISTINCT S.ID), COUNT(DISTINCT RM.MEMBER_ID)
FROM (SELECT B.ID, S.ID, RM.MEMBER_ID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.ID ORDER BY S.ID) as seqnum
      FROM BRANCH B 
      INNER JOIN STAFF S ON S.BRANCH_ID = B.ID
      INNER JOIN RECRUIT_MEMBER RM ON RM.BRANCH_ID = B.ID
     ) t
GROUP BY B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual table with only one salary per ID like this...

```
SELECT
   ...whatever fields you've already got...
   s.Salary
FROM
   ...whatever tables and joins you've already got...

   LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(SALARY) as "Salary" FROM SALARY_TABLE GROUP BY ID) s
   ON whatevertable.ID = s.ID
```

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately this didn't work! It seems it is still including the duplicate values in other joins!